# removing description tabs - single product page - breaks footer

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, tabs, troubleshooting

I would like to only dispaly the gallery & short despcription on the single product page.
Using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

unset( $tabs['description'] );          // Remove the description tab
unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );   // Remove the additional information tab

return $tabs;
}
```

The tabs disappear, but the footer does not display right anymore and gets distorted.

woocommerce.php:

```
?php
get_header();
?>
<div id="page-wrapper"> 
<div class="container">
    <section class="unique-feature-area-woo"> 

    </section>

    <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: footer.php   it is theme  file ?  which theme you can use?

Comment: sorry, it is the woocommerce.php NOT footer, I edited!